# Multiple reducers or multiple field in reducer

Tags: redux

I have `LOGIN_SUCCESS` and `CREATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS` actions.

Both of them should populate `user` field in `auth` reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
};
```

Also I have `LOGIN_FAILURE` and `CREATE_ACCOUNT_FAILURE` actions. On both actions I want to persist error message in state.

But I don't want to have same error message for both login and create account pages.

How to deal with `error` field in this case?  Should I create  2 error fields in state like this:

```
 const initialState = {
    user: null,
    isLoading: false,
    loginError: null, // <-----
    registrationError: null // <-----
};
```

Or better to have separate reducers for login and for create account? Create account reducer will only persist error message. And `auth` (login) reducer will handle both `LOGIN_SUCCESS` and `CREATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS` actions and persist `user` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've got a big problem here: logging in and registering are different things, and they need different error states. Have a value for each and keep them separate. You'll probably end up with other things in the reducer that deals with registering anyway (these things never stay simple for long!)